# How does a JIT compiler like v8 structure its memory (i.e. the stack, heap, code, and data)?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction, stack, v8

I am trying to figure out [how Linux stores the stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555289/what-data-structure-is-the-stack-using-in-linux), or C even, since each process can have its own stack. Every diagram shows the assembly instructions and registers used in managing an *extremely primitive* stack (only 1 stack as well), so I'm in doubt that this is how higher-level systems do it (i.e. systems with multiple threads, processes, fibers, workers, coroutines, generators, etc.). Which is why this question is about v8....

How does v8 (at a high level, maybe linking to some related code if it's useful) structure **the stack**? How does it structure the heap? And code and data. You always see diagrams like [this](https://people.kth.se/~johanmon/courses/id2206/lectures/processes-handout-nup.pdf):

[image]

But (a) is that how a production JIT system like v8 does it? And (b) what is the actual implementation of the key structs? What data structures are used? Is the stack *actually* a linked list of some sort? Or is it an array? Is the heap broken down into a doubly-linked list of blocks of a certain size? Are they allocated in physically contiguous blocks of memory (in v8), or are they using OS-specific syscalls like `mmap` on Linux to allocate memory, which it then structures in its own way using some sort of block architecture (which is what I would like to know about)? Or is it just relying on `malloc` and such?

Basically, I am interested in simulating how a production JIT compiler works and am stuck at the beginning part of how the memory is *structured* (with structs and such). I am not sure if the stack is **actually** a linked-list in reality, or something else. Am very much interested to know.

The reason I think these diagrams are a lie is because we are usually dealing with *virtual memory* here, the physical memory is abstracted away. And even then, the virtual memory is divided into small pages, which might be scattered around or something, I don't know. So I feel these visuals are totally incorrect and misleading, and would like to know what it actually looks like.

Comment: Have you looked at the [v8 source](https://github.com/v8/v8) or the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/kernel-stacks.html), or the [kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arc/kernel/head.S#L118)? You seem to be confused on [stack vs. heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap), and I'd recommend reading about [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), and [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347206).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does v8 structure the stack?

Just like any other program: `rbp` points at the base of the current function's stack frame, and `rsp` points at the "top" (growing downwards, though); the `push` and `pop` instructions are used to write/read from where `rsp` points to while decrementing/incrementing `rsp` accordingly. There's no data structure, just raw memory.

> Is the heap [...] using OS-specific syscalls like mmap on Linux to allocate memory

Yes. V8's managed heap is allocated one page at a time using `mmap`, or equivalents on other operating systems.
Note that what such diagrams call "heap" is heap-allocated memory in the C++ sense, not the managed heap in a VM sense. One could argue that the latter is just a special part/case of the former though, and whether you use `mmap` or `malloc` is an implementation detail that doesn't really matter (beyond possibly certain performance differences, depending on usage patterns).

> I think these diagrams are a lie is because we are usually dealing with virtual memory here

I'd put it the opposite way: virtual memory is why these diagrams are (slightly simplified but) mostly accurate. Every process thinks that it is alone in the world, it doesn't see any other processes in its memory address space (just a bit of the kernel, for interacting with it). The memory that a process sees does look like raw memory; it's just that the addresses aren't the physical addresses, there is a translation layer in between (which is managed by kernel + CPU).

Comment: But if v8 is using raw memory and assembly for the stack, how does it support multiple asynchronous processes or threads, each with their own stack? That’s what I’m talking about.

Comment: Again, just like any other program. Each process/thread has its own stack. The OS manages that, it's one of the core jobs a kernel has.

Comment: If I've understand your question, the memory of the thread's stack has no special property. For example, a process can have 4 stacks of 8K size, in process virtual addresses 8K-16K, 16K-24K, 24K-32K, and 32K-40K. Now (oversimplified), each time the task switcher (kernel, for example) gives a task to a given processor, it updates it's stack pointer (base and top), and the program continues from that. Without proper protection, if one stack grows beyond its size, it will override other stack (that happens in embedded a lot, for example). Does that makes it clearer?