# vmalloc() allocates from vm_struct list

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kmalloc, vmalloc

Kernel document https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand010.html says, that for `vmalloc`-ing

> It searches through a linear linked list of vm_structs and returns a new struct describing the allocated region.

Does that mean `vm_struct` list is already created while booting up, just like `kmem_cache_create` and `vmalloc()` just adjusts the page entries? If that is the case, say if I have a 16GB RAM in x86_64 machine, the whole `ZONE_NORMAL` i.e

```
16GB - ZONE_DMA - ZONE_DMA32 - slab-memory(cache/kmalloc)
```

is used to create `vm_struct` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That document is fairly old. It's talking about Linux 2.5-2.6. Things have changed quite a bit with those functions from what I can tell. I'll start by talking about code from kernel 2.6.12 since that matches [Gorman's explanation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand010.html) and is the oldest non-rc tag in the [Linux kernel Github repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags?after=v2.6.13-rc1).

The `vm_struct` list that the document is referring to is called `vmlist`. It is created [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.12/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L24) as a struct pointer:

```
struct vm_struct *vmlist;
```

Trying to figure out if it is initialized with any structs during bootup took some deduction. The easiest way to figure it out was by looking at the function [`get_vmalloc_info()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.12/source/fs/proc/mmu.c#L34) (edited for brevity):

```
if (!vmlist) {
    vmi->largest_chunk = VMALLOC_TOTAL;
}
else {
    vmi->largest_chunk = 0;
    prev_end = VMALLOC_START;

    for (vma = vmlist; vma; vma = vma->next) {
        unsigned long addr = (unsigned long) vma->addr;

        if (addr >= VMALLOC_END)
            break;

        vmi->used += vma->size;

        free_area_size = addr - prev_end;
        if (vmi->largest_chunk < free_area_size)
            vmi->largest_chunk = free_area_size;

        prev_end = vma->size + addr;
    }

    if (VMALLOC_END - prev_end > vmi->largest_chunk)
        vmi->largest_chunk = VMALLOC_END - prev_end;
}
```

The logic says that if the `vmlist` pointer is equal to NULL (`!NULL`), then there are no `vm_struct`s on the list and the `largest_chunk` of free memory in this `VMALLOC` area is the entire space, hence `VMALLOC_TOTAL`. However, if there is something on the `vmlist`, then figure out the largest chunk based on the difference between the address of the current `vm_struct` and the end of the previous `vm_struct` (i.e. `free_area_size = addr - prev_end`).

What this tells us is that when we `vmalloc`, we look through the `vmlist` to find the *absence* of a `vm_struct` in a virtual memory area big enough to accomodate our request. Only then can it create this new `vm_struct`, which will now be part of the `vmlist`.

`vmalloc` will eventually call [`__get_vm_area()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.12/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L163), which is where the action happens:

```
    for (p = &vmlist; (tmp = *p) != NULL ;p = &tmp->next) {
        if ((unsigned long)tmp->addr < addr) {
            if((unsigned long)tmp->addr + tmp->size >= addr)
                addr = ALIGN(tmp->size + 
                         (unsigned long)tmp->addr, align);
            continue;
        }
        if ((size + addr) < addr)
            goto out;
        if (size + addr <= (unsigned long)tmp->addr)
            goto found;
        addr = ALIGN(tmp->size + (unsigned long)tmp->addr, align);
        if (addr > end - size)
            goto out;
    }

found:
    area->next = *p;
    *p = area;
```

By this point in the function we have already created a new `vm_struct` named `area`. This for loop just needs to find where to put the struct in the list. If the `vmlist` is empty, we skip the loop and immediately execute the "found" lines, making `*p` (the `vmlist`) point to our struct. Otherwise, we need to find the struct that will go after ours.

So in summary, this means that even though the `vmlist` pointer might be created at boot time, the list isn't necessarily populated at boot time. That is, unless there are `vmalloc` calls during boot or functions that explicitly add `vm_struct`s to the list during boot as in future kernel versions (see below for kernel 6.0.9).

One further clarification for you. You asked if `ZONE_NORMAL` is used for the `vmlist`, but those are two separate memory address spaces. `ZONE_NORMAL` is describing physical memory whereas `vm` is virtual memory. There are lots of resources for explaining the difference between the two (e.g. [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347206/what-are-the-differences-between-virtual-memory-and-physical-memory)). The specific virtual memory address range for `vmlist` goes from `VMALLOC_START` to `VMALLOC_END`. In x86, those were [defined as](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.12/source/include/asm-x86_64/pgtable.h#L121):

```
#define VMALLOC_START    0xffffc20000000000UL
#define VMALLOC_END      0xffffe1ffffffffffUL
```

---

**For kernel version 6.0.9:**

The [creation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L2269) of the `vm_struct` list is here:

```
static struct vm_struct *vmlist __initdata;
```

At this point, there is nothing on the list. But in this kernel version there are a few boot functions that may add structs to the list:

```
   void __init vm_area_add_early(struct vm_struct *vm)
   void __init vm_area_register_early(struct vm_struct *vm, size_t align)
```

As for `vmalloc` in this version, the `vmlist` is now only a list used during initialization. `get_vm_area()` now calls `get_vm_area_node()`, which is a NUMA ready function. From there, the logic goes deeper and is much more complicated than the linear search described above.